# Does allocation speed depend on the garbage collector being used?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, memory-management

My app is allocating a ton of objects (>1mln per second; most objects are byte arrays of size ~80-100 and strings of the same size) and I think it might be the source of its poor performance.

The app's working set is only tens of megabytes. Profiling the app shows that GC time is negligibly small.

However, I suspect that perhaps the allocation procedure depends on which GC is being used, and some settings might make allocation faster or perhaps make a positive influence on cache hit rate, etc.

Is that so? Or is allocation performance independent on GC settings under the assumption that garbage collection itself takes little time?

Comment: are the objects you are allocating long lived or do they go out of scope as almost soon as they are created?

Comment: They are rather short lived: they go out of scope every 10-20 allocations or so.

Answer (score 2):

Of course your performance depends on the allocator used. But you have profiled GC and saw that it is not much of an issue. Also, one of the strengths of the GC is fast allocation at the expense of slower collection.

I think you are having issues with resulting fragmentation which makes memory access pattern problematic for the cpu, since it may need to invalidate its cache too often. Most GC algorithms doesn't reclaim space in an optimum way.

Since your working set is limited and predictable, you might want to use an object pool which is allocated beforehand. You may also want to use reference counting to avoid much of the manual memory management. Technically it is still GC but not in the common sense of the GC.

Still, I don't think the performance is much affected by how you manage memory but how you actually use, access it. Most likely your profiler has the definite answer.

Comment: ++ For the "pool" concept. On the other hand, reference counting? If you've got any bugs anywhere in the reference counting, they are very difficult to find.

Comment: Mike: It is not that hard to implement reference counting in this case. The pool objects don't contain references themselves.

And I didn't see the java tag.

Comment: Unfortunately my profiler gives me utter crap as its answer, and I've already asked a question about that on SO. I know a thing or two about profiling, but in this case I've failed, I'm going to try heavy artillery like VTune...

Comment: @jkff: My answer to that is - profilers are like that. Here's some real heavy artillery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct aspects to object allocation. The first is finding a suitable area of memory - with todays generational garbarge collectors, this is usually very fast (in the order of a few 10ths of machine cycles).

The second is the initialization of the objects you allocate. Since everything you allocate in Java is initialized, the cost for initialization can easily outweight the cost of allocation (except for the most simple, smallest objects). There is more. Since initialization requires writing the entire memory area the new object occupies (if you allocate a "new byte[1<<20]" for example, the entire megabyte needs to be set to zeros), this also usually pulls that memory into the cpu's cache, evicting other, older cache lines (which may or may not belong to your current "hot" working set).

If you do comparatively little processing on each of your arrays, those effects can severly affect the performance of your code. This can be partially avoided by re-using the same arrays over and over, but it usually makes the program logic more complex. It is also often not easy to determine if cache trashing is really the culprit. Its impossible to say from what little information is given in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Does your VM try to pool strings?  I had heard once, that IBM's VM did something like string interning but dynamically (no idea if its true) perhaps your VM is trying doing extra work to build an internal data structure of String internals.

Are you doing something like `byte b[] = new byte[100]; String s = new String(b);`  by any chance?  You might try not to allocate the String objects, and instead allocate some random object which has a reference to the byte[] (for comparison).

Comment: Yes, I am doing someting like the code you showed. But I need the strings for a variety of reasons.